# Can't access object property of a Mongoose response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm running this code on node.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.model('participant',new mongoose.Schema({},{ collection : 'forumParticipant' }));
var Participant = mongoose.model('participant');
mongoose.connect('******');

Participant.find({entity_id: 0}, function (err, docs) {
   console.log(docs[0]);
   console.log(docs[0].entity_id)
});
```

1) The first console.log return the full document

2) The second console.log return undefinied

I don't understand why.

I need to perform something like

```
var participants = docs.map(function(d){return d.user_id})
```

How can I achieve that? What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried flattening the result using `toObject()` like `var participants = docs.map(function(doc) {
  return doc.toObject().user_id;
})` or the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method which returns plain JS objects?

Comment: The issue was that mongoose doesn't return objects as they are in the database but actually returns objects wrapped inside objects proper to mongoose.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suspect the value you are trying to get is not in your `Schema` but is stored in your database.

You have two solutions from there. You can either add `entity_id` to your `Schema` and Mongo will be able to bind it to the `Document` object you receive. This is the recommended way.

Or you can bypass mongoose `Schema` and access the raw document stored in the database with `docs[0]._doc.entity_id`. I don't recommend this solution unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: The proper solutions is adding the property to the Schema and Masadow's bypass is a functional alternative.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped me. But for the `._id`, How can I access it, its not in my Schema, It returns undefind?

Comment: YES! This! It wasn't in the schema. so it was showing up on a full print of the Object, but not when accesing the key! Thank you!

Comment: " suspect the value you are trying to get is not in your Schema but is stored in your database." this line saves my day.. the FIELD IS NOT ON SCHEMA!

Answer (score 22):

Mongoose does funky stuff when it comes to accessing model properties. Your best bet whenever you're having problems, is either to use `.lean()` as part of your query, or call `.toObject()` on the output to convert the model into a plain JS object.

e.g. using `.toObject()`

```
Participant.find({entity_id: 0}, function (err, docs) {
   console.log(docs[0].toObject());
   console.log(docs[0].toObject().entity_id)
});
```

e.g. using `lean()`

```
Participant.find({entity_id: 0}).lean().exec(function (err, docs) {
   console.log(docs[0]);
   console.log(docs[0].entity_id)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Partipant.find({entity_id: 0})
```

The above find() returns the array of documents from DB

You can access the value of each record

```
docs.map((d)=>{
    console.log(d.get('user_id'))
})
```

Comment: And in case you only want to access one document, just use the `findOne` method instead of the `find` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the resolution is really simple, instead of find use findOne, because find can return many results and thats why when you try to go to the property of object it says undefined. If you use findOne, the query will definately have one result and then you would be able to use the item name and get the answer ex: object.item, If you want to use Model.find(), then you would need to access the first array in the result and then use it property, ex: object[0].item.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).