# Mongoose returning Array value as "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

About ready to frisbee my laptop into the drywall here.

I have a Mongo document containing several different objects and arrays. The main ones of interest are the `categories` array of objects and the `bypass` array of Strings.

I'm using `model.findOne()` to obtain the document with success. The value of the document is stored in the `res` variable and `console.log(res)` shows the correct values without errors. I can even SEE the contents of the `categories` and `bypass` elements.

When I assign `res.categories` to a variable, no errors occur. Hooray, the basics of assignment are working.

When I assign `res.bypass` to a variable (immediately after the above assignment), the variable value is `undefined` even though I can see the contents of `res.bypass` containing an Array of Strings as designed.

The structure of `res.bypass` is `bypass: [ '123', '456', '78', '90' ]`. Assigning that value to a variable sets it as `undefined`.

Am I missing something here? Am I not allowed to take a single document and assign its different elements to different variables?

EDIT 1:

Code Snippet Request:

```
await Api.findOne({ id: '1' }).then(async (doc) => {

    console.log(doc.categories) // Categories Array of Objects
    console.log(doc.bypass) // Bypass Array of Strings

    const categories = doc.categories // Value is categories Array of Objects
    const bypass = doc.bypass // Value is undefined
    ...
})
```

Comment: I think you should include your actual code or some part of it. Explaining it in prose form might be enjoyable. But I think code is easiest to grasp (at least for developers), well, in code form.

Comment: You might want to check whether you have spalled `res.bypass` correctly in your assignment statement

Comment: @thammada.ts Added code snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access object property of a Mongoose response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633561/cant-access-object-property-of-a-mongoose-response) You need to use `.lean()` & also make sure the field that you're trying to access is listed in schema..

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to wrap the promise callback in an `async` function, nor to use a `then` handler on an awaited promise. You should change it to:

```
const doc = await Api.findOne({ id: '1' });

console.log(doc.categories) // Categories Array of Objects
console.log(doc.bypass) // Bypass Array of Strings

const categories = doc.categories // Value is categories Array of Objects
const bypass = doc.bypass // Value is undefined
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately `doc.bypass` still returns undefined. Even though the root `doc` shows that `bypass: [ '123', '456', '78', '90' ]`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "root" doc?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that console.log(doc.bypass) logs the expected value? Can you add a screenshot maybe?