# Mongoose document returns "undefined" in dot notation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB document that returns certain values as `undefined` or `null` when referred to in dot notation.

Here is the structure of the document:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "categories": [], // Array of Category Objects
    "bypass": [] // Array of Strings
}
```

I'm using Mongoose as follows: `Model.findOne({ id: "1" }, { _id: 0 })` which returns the document with success, however, using dot notation to extract specific elements or assign them to variables causes certain ones to respond as null or undefined.

For example, if my returned document was stored in `doc`, `doc.categories` will return the full array, `[]`, of Category Objects I have created. `doc.version` returns `1.0.0`.

However, when I attempt `doc.bypass`, I get `undefined`. If I attempt `doc.id` I get `null`.

Anyone know what is happening?

CODE EDIT:

```
const doc = await Model.findOne({ id: "1" }, { _id: 0 });

console.log(doc); // Contains all document data including bypass with its Array of Strings
console.log(doc.bypass); // undefined
```

RETURN:

```
{
    id: '1',
    version: '1.0.0',
    categories: [
        {
            name: 'Category 1',
            id: '1111',
            active: true,
            children: [Array]
        },
        {
            name: 'Category 2',
            id: '2222',
            active: true,
            children: [Array]
        },
        {
            name: 'Category 3',
            id: '3333',
            active: true,
            children: [Array]
        },
        {
            name: 'Category 4',
            id: '4444',
            active: true,
            children: [Array]
        }
    ],
    bypass: [ '123', '456', '78', '90' ]
}
undefined
```

Comment: Im not quite sure how you are approaching this because there is no code example of how you are trying to approach retrieving the data - for instance, if you are running these requests for data within a promise or if they are bring run in a async function or call back, this could effect weather the data is being called back (because depending on when the code runs..... the data might not be there) - any chance of you adding a code example of when it does run compared to when it doesn't?

Comment: @Wally My apologies. Code edited in.

Comment: Can you please print the returned code for console.log(doc) // also side note - the second return has _id: 0 <<< is that correct with the _ ?

Comment: @Wally Yep. Output of above code included. Also, I added the `{ _id: 0 }` to avoid including the assigned MongoDB `_id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access object property of a Mongoose response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633561/cant-access-object-property-of-a-mongoose-response) You need to use `.lean()` & also make sure the field that you're trying to access is listed in schema..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the above then it should be working - so its more a question of how you have set up your model - for reference I've put below a working model, please check it against my example to see if yours is in line with that:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')

const Task = mongoose.model('Task', {
    description: {
        type: String, 
        trim: true,
        required: true
        },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
        }
})

module.exports = Task
```

If it is in line with this and you're still having the issue could I ask you to post your model in your code above?

Thanks -
W

Comment: Wally, it would seem it has been so long a day I completely forgot to update the Mongoose schema... Thank you!!!

Comment: No dramas @teej - I know the feeling well - happy to have been of help :)